# How to evict or delete pods from Kubernetes using golang client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to evict all pods from a Kubernetes node by using the client-go package. Similar to `kubectl drain <Node>`. Possibly ignoring the `kube-system` namespace pods.

I've obtained the list of pods from a node by:

```
func evictNodePods(nodeInstance string, client *kubernetes.Clientset) {

    pods, err := client.CoreV1().Pods("").List(metav1.ListOptions{
        FieldSelector: "spec.nodeName=" + nodeInstance,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, i := range pods.Items {
        if i.Namespace == "kube-system" {
            continue
        } else {
            //evict
        }
    }
}
```

But im not clear on how to send a POST request to evict the pods on a given node instance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete pod:

```golang
err := client.CoreV1().Pods(i.Namespace).Delete(i.Name, metav1.DeleteOptions{})
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

If you upgrade `client-go` to recent versions, you need to add [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) as a parameter too.

```golang
err := client.CoreV1().Pods(i.Namespace).Delete(context.TODO(), i.Name, metav1.DeleteOptions{})
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `Delete` may work most of the time, it does not guarantee that the new pod will not get scheduled on the same node. Here's how one should actually handle this:

##### Taint the node and make it unschedulable so that this node is taken out of the scheduling pool.

```golang
import (
  "context"

  "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
  meta_v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func CordonNode(client *kubernetes.Clientset, name string) error {
  # Fetch node object
  node, err := client.CoreV1().Nodes().Get(context.TODO(), name, meta_v1.GetOptions{})

  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  node.Spec.Unschedulable = true

  # Update the node
  _, err = client.CoreV1().Nodes().Update(context.TODO(), node, meta_v1.UpdateOptions{})

  return err
}
```

##### Now you have two options:

- Add the taint of `NoExecute` on node, kubelet will evict all the workloads for you from the node. However, the pods that tolerate this taint will still keep running on the node.

```golang
import (
  "context"

  "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
  meta_v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
  v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
)

func TaintNode(client *kubernetes.Clientset, name string) error {
  # Fetch node object
  node, err := client.CoreV1().Nodes().Get(context.TODO(), name, meta_v1.GetOptions{})

  node.Spec.Taints = append(node.Spec.Taints, v1.Taint{
    Key: "someKey"
    Value: "someValue"
    Effect: v1.TaintEffectNoExecute
  })

  # Update the node
  _, err = client.CoreV1().Nodes().Update(context.TODO(), node, meta_v1.UpdateOptions{})

  return err
}
```

- Individually evict workload pods running on that node.

```golang
import (
  "context"

  "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
  meta_v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
  policy "k8s.io/api/policy/v1beta1"
)

func EvictPod(client *kubernetes.Clientset, name, namespace string) error {
  return client.PolicyV1beta1().Evictions(namespace).Evict(context.TODO(), &policy.Eviction{
        ObjectMeta: meta_v1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      name,
            Namespace: namespace,
        }
}
```